# Angular use array value for oject

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I'm trying to set some object values via the values in an array.

```
$scope.ngmodelfield = {};
$scope.categories = [{
  cat: "Cat 1a",
  translationTag: "OccupationalSafety"
}, {
  cat: "Cat 1b",
  translationTag: "IndustrialSafety"
}, {
  cat: "Cat 2",
  translationTag: "Growth"
}, {
  cat: "Cat 3",
  translationTag: "Modifications"
}, {
  cat: "Cat 4",
  translationTag: "Maintenance"
}, {
  cat: "Cat 5",
  translationTag: "Renewals"
}, {
  cat: "Cat 6",
  translationTag: "Environment"
}, {
  cat: "Cat 7",
  translationTag: "IT"
}, {
  cat: "Cat 8",
  translationTag: "ResearchAndDevelopment"
}, {
  cat: "Cat 9",
  translationTag: "LegalRequirements"
}];
```

So I'm iterating over the objects the following way:

```
  <div class="row" ng-repeat="cat in categories track by $index">
    <div class="col s12">
      <div class="col s4">
        {{cat.cat}}  - {{cat.translationTag}}
      </div>
      <div class="col s8">
        <textarea ng-model="ngmodelfield.[cat.translationTag]" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Now I want to link the first textarea to `ngmodelfield.OccupationalSafety`, the second to `ngmodelfield.IndustrialSafety` and so on.

But this doesn't seem to work as shown here: http://plnkr.co/edit/WKCLjzmLy1IrwEmQPMRH?p=preview

Comment: Try `ngmodelfield[cat.translationTag]`, without a dot in between

Comment: agreed...that is a syntax error using `.[]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change:

```
<div class="col s8">
    <textarea ng-model="ngmodelfield.[cat.translationTag]" class="materialize-textarea">{{cat.cat}}</textarea>
</div>
```

to:

```
<div class="col s8">
     <textarea ng-model="ngmodelfield[cat.translationTag]" class="materialize-textarea">{{cat.cat}}</textarea>
</div>
```

That is, remove the dot from `ng-model="ngmodelfield.[cat.translationTag]"`.

Comment: don't make people compare differences themselves...explain the difference. A single dot is not always easy to spot and a proper answer should provide some explanation

Comment: @charlietfl thanks for the tip. In future I will try improve the quality of my answer

Answer (score 1):

There is a syntax error mixing two types of object property notation with `ngmodelfield`. Removing the dot in the `<textarea>` tag results in:

```
<textarea ng-model="ngmodelfield[cat.translationTag]" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
```

When wanting to dynamically create a new property on an object that is unknown at design time, use bracket notation, as above.  When you know the object's property before hand, you can reference it using dot notation.

Answer (score -1):

```
// this is the only change that you need to do

<textarea ng-model="ngmodelfield[cat.translationTag]" class="materialize-textarea">{{cat.cat}}</textarea>
```

Comment: It needs to be saved in `ngmodelfield `, as mentioned in the post